# select mutiple id's inside not() jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to put multiple element id's inside not selector in jquery. How can I do that?Below is the present code

```
$('#submit_form :input').not('#contbutton').blur(function () {
//logic
```

});

But now I need multiple id's inside not like

```
$('#submit_form :input').not('#contbutton #fn #ln').blur(function () {
//logic
```

});
Is it possible?

Comment: add a comma in between

Comment: If you're able to modify the markup, it would be more logical to give these related `input` elements a similar `class` or `data-*` attribute instead.

Comment: I tried adding comma in between. But it doesn't seem to be working.I am trying in IE8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seperate selector inside `not` with `,`

```
 $('#submit_form :input').not('#contbutton,#fn,#ln').blur(function () {
     ....
```

Comment: that should work.. that is how you select multiselector ..anyways are u getting any errors